# Create a column in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I´m creating a project in laravel 5.2, I need to know if is possible to change a table, creating new columns without using command lines using artisan

For example there is a table named Products, and requires that the User is able to create new columns (column1, column2, etc.), just typing the name of the column and clicking the OK button.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why is the user creating database columns?

Comment: You can probably run a `\DB::raw()` statement for altering a table, like `\DB::raw("ALTER TABLE ... ")`, but that's a lot of responsibility to give to a user. Unless you're attempting to code a web-based database-management  tool (think PHPMyAdmin) you'd be better off using `migrations`

Comment: You can run Artisan commands without command line, fyi.

Comment: @Leonardo I dont think the question is very clear. Do you want users to add columns or rows? See my answer if rows.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that you want to add rows (Products) not collins so that is how my answer is geared.

A row being as below graphically:

```
| Heading 1 (Column) | Heading 2 (Column) |
|--------------------|--------------------|
| Usr Added Row 1    | Usr Added Row 1    |
| Usr Added Row 2    | Usr Added Row 2    |
| Usr Added Row 3    | Usr Added Row 3    |
```

The code to add a column:

```
DB::insert('insert into users (id, name) values (?, ?)', [1, 'Dayle']);
```

Assuming table is called users with rows id and name.

See documentation [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database)
I hope this helps, comment if you need anymore help.